How to efficiently merge two sorted lists in Python?
I'm looking to merge two sorted lists in Python without using extra space for a third list. Is there an in-place method to do this efficiently? Here's what I've tried so far, but it seems inefficient:
def merge_sorted_lists(a, b):
    for i in range(len(b)):
        a.append(b[i])
        a.sort()

Any suggestions for improvement?
The provided code snippet tries to merge two pre-sorted lists by appending elements from the second list (b) to the first list (a) and then sorting a again after each append operation.

Use the sorted built in function. There is also a sort method on lists. I am more familiar with the sorted method. Add the two lists together sorted(list_a + list_b).

@Shmack that would create two additional lists, list_a + list_b then the sorted version.

If they're both sorted to start with, you can do this most efficiently using bisection. You'll have to pay some cost on resizes of the underlying arrays though.

@Shmack, sorted(x) offers no efficiency improvement over x.sort() -- and having presorted inputs allows an O(n+m) implementation, so not taking advantage of knowing your inputs are already sorted is needlessly doing far more work than necessary..

@CharlesDuffy I'm curious: Are there Python implementations where sorted(list_a + list_b) isn't O(n+m)?

@nocomment, ...fair point that timsort takes advantage of runs, yes -- but it needs to find them first, so it's more work than just jumping direct to the merge.

@CharlesDuffy Depends on how costly comparisons are and in what language you implement the merge. If the elements are normal-size ints and you write the merge in Python, you don't stand a chance (at least in CPython ... I'm not familiar with others).

@nocomment, if you want to argue that heapq.merge is slower than timsort, the place to do that is in the linked duplicate.

@nocomment, ...I also feel like you're putting words in my mouth -- like implying that I was suggesting putting together a native-Python implementation. I don't believe I ever made any such suggestion.

@CharlesDuffy Nah, wasn't implying that. Just providing some information from myself.

@CharlesDuffy Wait, why did you bring up heapq.merge? Do you think that's written in C?

@nocomment, brought it up because it's the accepted answer on the linked duplicate. If you want to argue that timsort will do better, that's the relevant competition. (I haven't looked at the implementation, but there wouldn't be much point in including it in the standard library if it didn't outperform the stock tool for the special case it's built to handle).

@CharlesDuffy Meh, at least for two inputs, it's not really competitive. It's Python code using heap functions. They're in C, but it's still costly. Easy to beat.
